# Property '' does not exist on type 'Request<ParamsDictionary>'

Tags: javascript, typescript, express, typescript-typings

When trying to extend the `Request` interface from the package `express` to add some custom properties, I'm getting the following typescript error:

`TS2339: Property '' does not exist on type 'Request<ParamsDictionary>'.`

Do you know how to solve that?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Since a recent update of its [typings](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/express) and dependencies, I found that the following should fix the errors in your application.

In your `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    //...
    "typeRoots": [
      "./custom_typings",
      "./node_modules/@types"
    ],
  }
// ...
}
```

And in your custom typings

```js
// custom_typings/express/index.d.ts
declare namespace Express {
    interface Request {
        customProperties: string[];
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah, it does fix but when just created `index.d.ts` file on root folder my VScode stopped showing error but I was still getting error on terminal, so I did as you described but directly created `index.d.ts` file inside `custom_typings` and still it was giving error, it went after creating `express` folder,  so why is that `express` folder mandatory ?

Comment: You can either create a directory named `express` or having a file named `express.d.ts` to tell typescript that you are aiming this specific module

Comment: @RohitAmbre did you figure out how to fix it. Vscode seems to have no issues but compiler showing some errors.

Comment: @danie_man, I did like what I have explained in my comment and it works without any compiler issue you can check [here](https://github.com/rohit-ambre/express-ts)

Answer (score 4):

Just add the following, what this does is it simply adds a custom property to the express Request interface

```
declare global {
  namespace Express {
    interface Request {
      propertyName: string; //or can be anythin
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this, could you explain how this works a bit more? I've never seen someone use declare global

Answer (score 4):

I recently had the same issue, I followed the solution in the previous comments and this [repo](https://github.com/3mard/ts-node-example) and I still had the same issue. After doing more digging it seems like it's a bug with [ts-node](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/745).

To solve this you need to run your server with a --files flag

So if you normally run your server
`ts-node ./src/server.ts` or `nodemon ./src/server.ts`
Change it to
`ts-node --files ./src/server.ts` or `nodemon --files ./src/server.ts`

After that, I was able to get rid of both the VScode errors and errors while starting the server.

Comment: Thank you for your answer you save my day ! I didn't understand why vscode told me my config is right but by running the project it still shows the errors. I didn't expected to be a ts-node bug...

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was missing types for express. What I'm currently working on is migrating our codebase from Yarn to PNPM. The difference with PNPM is it doesn't hoist dependencies the way Yarn does so I had to add the dependencies on the package.json for each workspace that would use that dependency.

This is the error I encountered:

```
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
../server/src/api/filters/googleFilter.ts:6:23 - error TS2339: Property 'headers' does not exist on type 'Request<core.ParamsDictionary>'.

6   const idToken = req.headers.authorization;
```

It took me quite a few searches to look for a fix when I decided to open up the `node_modules` folder of that workspace. Inside `node_modules/@types/express/index.d.ts`

```
/// <reference types="express-serve-static-core" />
/// <reference types="serve-static" />

import * as bodyParser from "body-parser";
import serveStatic = require("serve-static");
import * as core from "express-serve-static-core";
import * as qs from "qs";
```

I saw my IDE showing errors telling me that it cannot find the types for `express-serve-static-core` and `serve-static` so what I did was to add it on the package.json of that workspace and that fixed the errors on the terminal.

Hope this helps someone else who will encounter the same issue with PNPM.

Answer (score 0):

**This worked for me!**

## Using `ts-node`

Add the following file to add a property to the express Request interface as suggested by [@Rishav Sinha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7001694/rishav-sinha)

1. Add this file `src/types/types.custom.d.ts`

```json
declare global {
    declare namespace Express {
        interface Request {
            user?: any,
            page?: number,
        }
    }
}

// If this file has no import/export statements (i.e. is a script)
// convert it into a module by adding an empty export statement.
export { }
```

2. Add in `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    //...
    "typeRoots": [
      "./types",
      "./node_modules/@types"
    ],
  }
// ...
}
```

3. Run this command with `--files` options as suggested by [@Shahar Sharron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4594019/shahar-sharron)

If you installed globally `ts-node`

```
$ ts-node --files ./src/index.ts
```

or to run from your project dependencies `ts-node`

```
$ npx ts-node --files ./src/index.ts
```

## Using `nodemon`

If you want to use `nodemom`

1. Add this file in folder project `nodemon.json`

```
{
    "watch": ["src/**/*.ts"],
    "ext": "ts,json",
    "ignore": [
        "src/**/*.spec.ts",
        "src/**/*.test.ts"
    ],
    "exec": "npx ts-node --files ./src/index.ts"
}
```

2. Run `nodemon`

```
$ nodemon
```

Answer (score 0):

Only these two changes solved errors for me both vscode and compilation:

First create your declaration file and put this code a folder named `typings`:

Folder name is important:

`typings/` or `src/typings/`

File name is not important:

`index.d.ts` `global.d.ts` `index.ts` ...

```
import { Request, Response } from "express";

declare global {
  namespace Express {
    export interface Request {
      propertyNameA: string;
      propertyNameB: string;
    }
    export interface Response {
      propertyNameA: string;
      propertyNameB: string;
      propertyNameC: string;
    }
  }
}

// This line has no function
export { Request, Response };
```

Now, there are two alternatives:

A. Add `--files` flag to your ts-node or nodemon execution expression

Example:  `ts-node --files src/app.ts`

B. Or update ts-config.json file like:

```
{
  "ts-node": { 
    "files": true 
  },
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Visit https://aka.ms/tsconfig.json to read more about this file */
    /* --- */
  }
}
```

- https://typestrong.org/ts-node/docs/options/#files
- https://typestrong.org/ts-node/docs/troubleshooting/#missing-types