# Adding parameter to existing type using typeRoots

Tags: typescript, express

I am trying to add a typeorm instance to the express request object as described in my other question: [Pass ORM object to router in express](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72894810/4923949).

The answer suggests to do this by adding it as Middleware.

```
app.use((req,res,next)=>{
req.dataSource = appDataSource
next();
});
```

However I get the error:`Property 'dataSource' does not exist on type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>'.ts(2339)`

To solve this I tried this approach https://stackoverflow.com/a/58957229/4923949. I modified my tsconfig and added:

```
    "typeRoots": [
      "./src/custom_typings",
      "./node_modules/@types",
    ],
```

And I added a `/src/custom_typings/express.d.ts` with the content:

```
import { DataSource } from "typeorm";

declare namespace Express {
  interface Request {
    dataSource: DataSource;
  }
}
```

Why am I still getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add express.d.ts like that

> /src/custom_typings/express/express.d.ts

without changing in typeRoots.

that was counsel from [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58957228/property-does-not-exist-on-type-requestparamsdictionary)
that helped me